# Trying to create a slideshow of images

Tags: swift, macos, slideshow

I am trying to make a slideshow of images from a folder but i don't know how to load the images from a folder in order and then display them onscreen. I am using an NSTimer to switch pictures but it only works if I know the filename for each image.

This is for a program that runs on Mac. I have tried NSFileManager according to other answers I have found on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't get them to work. I am using NSImage to load the image onto the view.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do it yourself. Apple created for that (and more) the IKImage Kit. (Read the docs about that.) Here a short part of `Image Kit Programming Guide`:

*A slideshow is a popular way for consumers to view digital images. The IKSlideshow class and the IKSlideshowDataSource protocol provide an easy way for your application to support slideshows of images . . .*

Comment: I tried to use Image Kit but there is barely any documentation about it and I can't seem to find any documentation regarding it. Do you have any leads?

Comment: You find the Image Kit Programming Guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004907-CH1-SW1)
and the class description [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartz/ikimageview?language=objc) And a small program IKImageView Demo), what does not exactly do what you want, but may help anyway [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/IKImageViewDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)